# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics

Tags: android, dex

I got error while executing my android application. what's the actual problem of this. anyone know post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **multiple** project dependencies that use the *same* classes.

In this case, `com.google.android.gms.analytics` is duplicated - so you should ensure you are only using this library once.

Check your `build.gradle` file, your `libs` folder and anywhere else you define dependencies.

I believe if you use `com.google.android.gms:play-services` as a dependency, newer versions contain Google Analytics by default

Comment: am using eclipse and android stand alone sdk. am try all steps i wont get it....

Answer (score 0):

```
  android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```